# Listview cannot detect onitemclick event

Tags: android, android-listview, onclicklistener

I have a listview but somehow it cannot detect on click listener although I've tripple checked the code and I cannot find what is the problem... So please help me if you can

Here is my downloaded xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/topbar" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/downloaded_back_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/back" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/downloaded_layout_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/downloaded_back_img"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/downloaded_my_title"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/downloaded_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the listitem xml that Im populating:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_item_sel"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/downloaded_album_itempic"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:padding="1dip" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="70"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/downloaded_album_itemtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/downloaded_album_itemsinger"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/downloaded_album_itemgenre"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/downloaded_album_item_delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:drawableTop="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
        android:text="@string/delete" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:background="@drawable/item_arrow"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And part of my activity's code that maybe is related to the listview:

```
public class Downloaded extends Activity {
    private DatabaseHelper helper;
    private DownloadedAlbumLazyAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<Albums> temp;
    private ListView list;
    private ImageView back;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.downloaded);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.downloaded_list);
        back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.downloaded_back_img);
        back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        temp = new ArrayList<Albums>();
        helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        helper.openDB();
        temp = helper.getAllDownloadedAlbums();

        adapter = new DownloadedAlbumLazyAdapter(this, temp);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,
                    long arg3) {
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.putExtra("songs", temp.get(position).getSongs());
                i.setClass(Downloaded.this, DownloadedDetails.class);
                // startActivity(i);
                Toast.makeText(
                        Downloaded.this,
                        getString(R.string.downloaded_my_title) + " "
                                + temp.get(position).getSongs().size()
                                + " items", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        helper.closeDB();
    }
```

I cannot figure out what is causing this problem. This activity is inside in tabhost, and other activities have listviews but all work.

Comment: You have to make focusable=false to all other listitem object.

Comment: what your logcat says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should extend from `ListActivity` instead of `Activity`:

```
public class Downloaded extends ListActivity
```

Then do any initialization in the `onCreate()` method. You can use `getListView()` to reference yout list:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    ...
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(...);
    ...
}
```

If you have a button in your `ListView` you should set it's `focusable` property to false in the `getView()` method of you adapter:

```
deleteButton.setFocusable(false);
deleteButton.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```

This way your list item receives the event.

Cheers!

Comment: One thing missing: `setFocusable()` is to be used in the `getView()`method of you adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
public class Downloaded extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {
}


@Override
public void onItemClick(View v){
}
```

OR...

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new View.OnItemClickListener() {
```